# How to pass a renderer function with parameters to a component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a customizable avatar upload component like this:

```
<AvatarUpload
  ...
  renderSaveButton=({disabled}) => <Button disabled={disabled}>...</Button>
/>
```

As you can see the `renderSaveButton` function defines how the button should be rendered. More importantly, it also receives a parameter from the internal state of the `AvatarUpload` component.

Then in the `AvatarUpload` component itself, I render the button this way:

```js
{renderSaveButton({disabled: value)}
```

The problem is that the linter is complaining that React is going to create a new function on every render, and I should not do it (the message is "do not define components during render").

Shall I care about this warning, and if so what's the alternative?

I searched on google but it's not clear to me what's the alternative to this render props technique.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no measurable performance hit using an inline anonymous callback function then I don't see any issue with this. It's just a warning.

If there is a performance issue or you just really want to clear out all warnings then you can memoize the callback that is passed to children components using the `useCallback` hook.

Example:

```
const renderSaveButton = useCallback(({ disabled }) => (
  <Button disabled={disabled}>
    ...
  </Button>
), [/* place any dependencies here */]);

...

<AvatarUpload ... renderSaveButton={renderSaveButton} />
```